# When we worship a deva, what are we worshipping?

Tags: gods, rituals, worship, vedic-gods, prayer

When we perform a ritual invoking the name of a deva, are we worshipping the person holding the office of the deva, or the office itself?
For example, when we invoke Chandra in a ritual, are we worshipping the person who happens to be holding the office of Chandra right now, or are we worshipping the office of Chandra itself?

If you choose to cite verses from scripture in your answer, then please also cite scholars to support your interpretation of scripture.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community So when we talk about a deva, we are actually talking about a title that has been held by multiple persons, right?

Comment: For example, "Indra" is a position that has been held by different persons than the person holding it right now.

Comment: The position is eternal, but the person holding the position is mortal.

Comment: So when we invoke a deva in a ritual, are we invoking the mortal person holding the position of the deva, or the eternal position itself?